# C: Bitwise little-endian confusion

Tags: c, bitmap, bitwise-operators, bmp, endianness

I am trying to read the header of a BMP file and extract the width from it.
I know that the file format uses little-endian format, so I read it byte-per-byte, and wrote this function to assemble an integer from 4 chars/bytes:

```
int assembleInt(char pos1, char pos2, char pos3, char pos4)
{
  new_int = 0;
  new_int += (pos4 << 24);
  new_int += (pos3 << 16);
  new_int += (pos2 << 8);
  new_int += pos1;
  return new_int;
}
```

To me, this looks like it should work.
If I read the width of a bitmap that is 1200*1200, I get 944. I have opened the file in a hex editor to check, and the file is okay.

I thought maybe it's because I'm trying to shift a char out of bounds, so I changed it to this:

```
int shifter = 0;
new_int += (shifter + pos4) << 24;
```

but it didn't solve anything.
I hope you can help me, thanks a lot!

Comment: pos4 << 24 - you are shifting too much for char, try casting pos4 to larger value-then you can shift

Comment: Tried that, gets the same result.

Comment: 1200 is 0x4B0, 944 is 0x3B0. So how would that happen with a shift problem? You don't accidentally get 0x300 by shifting 4 by the improper amount. Could something else be wrong? Are those chars correct?

Comment: `(pos4 << 24)` is undefined behaviour if `pos4 >0x7F`. what type is `new_int`?

Comment: @gio nope. `char` has lesser conversion rank than that of `int`, so if `char` appears as the first operand of a shift operator, it is promoted to `int`.

Comment: did you try `return ((unsigned) pos4 << 24) + (pos3 << 16) + (pos2 << 8) + pos1;`?

Comment: @mch yes, I had that at first. Changed it to avoid confusing, got the same result.

Comment: @harold I checked the chars, they are correct.

Comment: @BigBadWolf so pos2 is 4, then you shift it, and you get 0x300?

Comment: @harold Now that you say it, it seems odd to me as well. I inserted printf's everywhere to check every value at every step, and it all seems correct except the result.

Comment: Wait! I got it. Your chars are signed. `pos1 = 0xB0`, which is negative, hence the trouble.

Comment: @harold oh my god. Thank you. THIS is why I should use uint8_t instead of chars for this stuff.

Comment: @mch Changed everything to uint8_t, and it works.

Comment: @harold: Good catch. You should write that as an answer (which it is) :-).

Comment: @harold I agree, you took a lot of valuable time to help me and you managed to find the source in that little snippet I gave you. You should post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem actually wasn't in the shifts, for the number 1200 something goes from in this line:

```
new_int += pos1;
```

There `pos1` is implicitly converted to an `int`, and since it is a signed `char` with value 0xB0 (1200 = 0x4B0), it is interpreted as negative. That shows up as "1 less in the next byte".

The other lines have the same problem, but it is not expressed when the value 1200 is used. That made this problem particularly sneaky, since every intermediate value that you're likely to look at would be observed to be correct, while the wrong value is created in a line that looks like it couldn't be wrong. And in a way that line isn't really wrong, the types were wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The BITMAPFILEHEADER does not have the width information. The BITMAPINFOHEADER has the width in the biWidth field, which is a 32  bit long of Intel-endianness (little-endian). The BITMAPINFOHEADER is at the beginning of the DIB, directly after the BITMAPFILEHEADER. You can access it as:

```
char *pDIB;  // the bitmap
width= ((LPBITMAPINFOHEADER)pDIB)->biWidth;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I meant just the binary header, the leading 54 bytes in my case, which I am reading using fread and storing it in a uint8_t dynamic memory. The problem was solved by @harold, it appeared that I was using signed chars for the conversion function instead of uint8's.